# Netbeans javascript project not re-compiling

Tags: javascript, netbeans

I'm trying to learn javascript using netbeans 8.0.  When I make a ***change to my project title*** in index.html and re-run the project, it isn't showing the change in the browser.  I tried Run->Clean and Build Main Project, but when I choose Debug->File, it doesn't show the change.  When I look in projects, the project name is in bold, so it's set as the main project.  Any ideas?

I searched online but nothing is turning up for my issue. It says [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/webclient/html5-gettingstarted.html) that changes are supposed to auto-compile as they are done.  This should be easy, but I'm not seeing why the title change isn't showing when I Debug.  This may seem easy, but the real issue is that other changes aren't showing when I run the web page also.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery My Project</title>
        <link href="css/polaris/polaris.css" rel="stylesheet">
...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Preventing future caching issues**

To reduce some potential caching issues, it's best to have **Internet Explorer** set to request the latest version of the page rather than relying on a cached copy.  To do this:

From the Tools menu choose Internet Options.

On the `General tab` under `Browsing history` click `Settings`.

Under `Check for newer versions of stored pages` make sure

`Every time I visit the webpage` is selected.

Click the OK button.

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe it, but when I closed the tabs with the project open and re-ran or debug the project the changes weren't showing up.

When I refreshed the web page, the change showed up.  This was with Internet Explorer browser.  So apparently, it was compiled, but the browser was using the old version instead of the new version.